# Confusion with window.onload

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I just copy pasted this bit from a book:

```
window.onload = init;
function init() {
var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
button.onclick = handleButtonClick();
}
function handleButtonClick() {
alert("Button has been clicked");
}
```

The problem is that the alert appears when I load the page, not when I click on the button. Does anybody why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
button.onclick = handleButtonClick();
```

to

```
button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
```

(Without the `()`.)

Your original line, `button.onclick = handleButtonClick();` *calls* the `handleButtonClick` function and then assigns its return value to `button.onclick`. It's exactly like

```
var a = foo();
```

...which *calls* `foo` and then assigns its return value to `a`.

You don't want to do that, you just want to assign the function *reference* to `onclick`. So you refer to the function by its name, without calling it (so, without the `()`).